# Regex in Java - Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem in Regular expression. I need to print and count the words starts with word ‘ge’ and end with either word ‘ne’ or ‘me’. When I running the code only words start with "ge" appear. Can anyone help me to improve my source code?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ge\\s*(\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

int count=0;
List<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();

while (m.find()) {
    count++;
    outputs.add(m.group());
    System.out.println(m.group());
}

System.out.println("The count is " + count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\bge\w*[nm]e\b
```

This should do it for you.

In java this would be

```
\\bge\\w*[nm]e\\b
```

use `\b` to denote `word boundary`

Answer (score 0):

Well you're kinda missing the second half of your regex

```
ge\s*(\w+)[nm]e
```

This will work.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hN7cU2/1)